How to resolve issue in admin configuration right side tabs not able to open
How to resolve the issue in Magento 2.4.7-p3 version admin grid is not able to open.
While you are in developer mode and go to store -> configuration-> and open any left tab and now open child right side tab it is not opend and returns error like
Uncaught TypeError: ah.attachEvent is not a function.


Hello dear please apply static content deploy commands in your root directory.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
